# Inbound SMTP Access Problem

Tags: smtp

I setup an e-mail server(smarter mail) in my vps. Everything works fine except the inbound SMTP server. I can send email but cannot receive. All the required ports and programs are allowed on firewall.

Hosting company told me that port 26 and 2525 is dedicated for SMTP communication. I set 26 as default port.

```
telnet mail.mydomain.com 26
```

command works successfully from outside. So I dont understand what the problem is. Why other mail servers cannot access? Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2):

Other mail servers are only able to send mail to your servers on the standard port 25. Port 26 and 2525 are probably for you to use to send mail through it to the web if configured specifically (ie: in Outlook), but regular servers do not know this. They can only send mail to you on port 25.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to handle this? Cant I redirect port 25 to 26 somehow ?

Comment: My feeling is that your service provider is blocking inbound/outbound port 25 to prevent you from sending mail (mainly to block spammers). If this is the case, there's really nothing you can do from your end.

Comment: no they dont block port 25

Comment: Dynamic DNS services help get around the ISP port 80 blocking. There is "probably" =) a dynamic SMTP service that will help you get around the port 25 blocking.  Not sure if your ISP will like this since it's against TOS for most non-business ISP accounts.